# Is VS supporting C?

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, codeblocks

I am currently learning C and I am using Code Blocks. I think that VS as an IDE is more modern and would run better. So I have 2 questions. Does VS support C? And if so, is it worth it moving from Codeblocks to VS? I mean Codeblocks is built to run C but while VS isn't, so will I gain anything from changing my IDE?

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Microsoft has tons of C code in the Windows core. Don't think they use CodeBlocks.

Comment: Huh? You pretend VS is not made for writing C programs?? Visual Studio is definitely made for developing C programs (and other languages too BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can use any compiler. Visual Studio has also built in very nice Cmake & VC support.

If you want to compile as C using standard msvc compiler you need to set it in the project properties:

[image]

The only problem is that msvc still does not fully support C99 features.

If you want to use gcc you need to set it up in the project properties (this example is for g++ and C++ but you simply need to change the compiler.
[image]

There is plenty information on the net how to set the intellisense to be gcc & clang compatible (VS uses Edison Design Group intellisense)

Comment: "The only problem is that msvc still does not fully support C99 features." --> I thought VS moved to C11 compliance, skipping the C99 mandatory VLA.  [ref](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica maybe. I usually do not use msvc

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Visual Studio you can compile and execute your C programmes and I will say it was not worth it as we are learners and IDE's has tons of features which will make you confused and because of the autocomplete we can't practice properly '_'.

Comment: If you are a proffesional developer you can use VS.I'm using VSCode (Code editor not an IDE)

Comment: _because of the autocomplete we can't practice properly_ (!?). I'd say the contrary is true.